Coefficient identification with polynomials and exponential functions
I need to evaluate the constants which satisfy the equation:
$$(1-x^2)e^0 -\frac{1}{4}(1-x^2)e^{-2x} - \frac{1}{4}(1-x^2)e^{2x} = C_0e^0 + \frac{1}{2}C_1(3x^2-1)e^0+\frac{1}{8}C_2(1-x^2)e^{-2x}+3C_3(1-x^2)e^{2x}$$
I'm thinking of collecting terms together based on degrees of the polynomials and exponentials to get:
$$\Big(1-C_0+\frac{1}{2}C_1\Big)e^0x^0 - (1+\frac{3}{2}C_1)e^0x^2 - \Big(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8}C_2\Big)(1-x^2)e^{-2x} - \Big(\frac{1}{4}+3C_3\Big)(1-x^2)e^{2x} = 0$$
Am I allowed to split this up into 4 different equations:

$\Big(1-C_0+\frac{1}{2}C_1\Big)= 0$
$- (1+\frac{3}{2}C_1) = 0$
$- \Big(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8}C_2\Big) = 0$
$- \Big(\frac{1}{4}+3C_3\Big) = 0$

and solve $C_2$ and $C_3$ directly and use a system of equations to solve $C_0$ and $C_1$?

If this is an identity, it is true for all $x$. Use Taylor series. and collect powers.

@ClaudeLeibovici Are you saying to create and write out the Taylor series of each polynomial (or product of polynomial and exponential) on the left and right side? Does the center matter? I'll assume we would want to truncate it after the 2nd or 3rd term

Since this is supposed to be an identity, make it around $x=0$

@ClaudeLeibovici Okay! I'll set up a Maclaurin series for each term, and rearrange and see what I get!

@ClaudeLeibovici Rewriting each term into a Taylor series up to the 2nd degree yields: $$(1-x^2)\Big[1-1/4(1+2x+2x^2) - 1/4(1-2x+2x^2)\Big] = C_0 +1/2C_1(3x^2-1)+(1-x^2)\Big[1/8 C_2 (1-2x+2x^2) + 3C_3(1+2x+2x^2)\Big]$$ and reorganizing in terms of powers: $$(1-x^2)\Big[(1/2 - 1/8 C_2 - 3C_3) + 2x(1/4 C_2 - 6C_3) - x^2(1+1/4C_2 + 6C_3)\Big] - C_0 - 1/2 C_1(3x^2-1) = 0$$. Does this look right so far?
